# Hide/Show <paragraph> with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, breakpoints

I've coded a site, but I have a question - I have 2 different paragraphs in the same div, but one of them should only show when the screen is 600 or over. Can it be done this way? or should I wrap my

in a secondary  inside the first

```
 <span class="me-square">
            <div class="me-wrapper">
                <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
                <p>My name is Katrine, but my friends call me Mira. I’m 20 years old and I live in Denmark. 
                <p id="me-2ndtext">I want this text to only show when the screen is 600 or over</p>
    </div></span>
```

CSS

```
#me-2ndtext{
    display: none;
} 

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div#me-2ndtext {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be ```p#me-2ndtext``` not ```div```.

Comment: why do you want to use different selectors? i would recommend to use only `#me-2ndtext` in media query, too.

Comment: And FYI, div in span is illegal nesting.

Comment: For a good code, please try use a class like a '.is-invisible' because you can reuse this code without having to create the same style again. And avoid using IDs for style is better to use class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go like this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 601px) {
    #me-2ndtext {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Version**

HTML:

```
<span class="me-square">
    <div class="me-wrapper">
        <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
        <p>My name is Katrine, but my friends call me Mira. I’m 20 years old and I live in Denmark. 
        <p id="me-2ndtext">I want this text to only show when the screen is 600 or over</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    p#me-2ndtext {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Or when it's all times the second paragraph you can make it like this:**

You don't need the extra id then.

HTML:

```
<span class="me-square">
    <div class="me-wrapper">
        <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
        <p>My name is Katrine, but my friends call me Mira. I’m 20 years old and I live in Denmark. 
        <p>I want this text to only show when the screen is 600 or over</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    p:nth-of-type(2) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```